# IBM Worklight invokeCastIron can't connect to Cast Iron Live instance

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Cast Iron Live instance working with a simple query to Salesforce.com. When I enter the URL in my browser or via curl I get the expected response back.

When I try to invoke the equivalent of the same URL in the IBM Worklight adapter, the server continually comes back with 401 Unauthorized HTML response.

I've looked for more detailed logs of the actual request Worklight is sending, with no luck. I've also installed Wireshark and sniffed my connection in hopes that I could see the URL or headers, but they're encrypted along with the payload. I've also looked at the Worklight Server JavaScript source for clues, but most of the real work is done in Java class files.

Here's my working Cast Iron URL (specifics anonymized, all on a single line):
    https://eval-provide.castiron.com/envq/Development/getProducer? 
    ciUser=admin@mydomain.com&ciPassword=My@ss4d!

Here's my adapter code (again, anonymized):
    function getProducers() {

```
var input = {
        method  : 'get',
        appName : 'producers'
        requestType: 'https',
        path: '/envq/Development/getProducer',
        parameters: {
            ciUser:     'admin@mydomain.com',
            ciPassword: 'My@ss4d!'
        },
        returnedContentType : 'xml'     
};
return WL.Server.invokeCastIron(input);
}
```

appName and requestType seem to be ignored. I've tried it with them and without them.

I've also tried not using the parameters and hardcoding the path to the full string I used in the URL, ie (all on one line of course):

```
path : '/envq/Development/getProducer? 
        ciUser=admin@mydomain.com&ciPassword=My@ss4d!',
```

What do I need to do to get Cast Iron Live and Worklight to authenticate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Cast Iron instance is being protected by basic auth, you'll need to pass the username and password in its bas64 format like this:

```
    var input = {
            method  : 'get',
            appName : 'myApp',
            headers: {Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW5Ad29ya2xpZ2h0LmlibTpjaGFuZ2VJdCE="},
            path : '/env/Development/'+orchestrationName,           
            returnedContentType : 'json'

    };
    return WL.Server.invokeCastIron(input);
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Cast Iron requires basic auth in the headers in base64 format. Specifically, the Base 64 string must be in username:password format. Once I did that and rebuilt my adapter it worked. Thanks so much for your help!