# CastIron adapter. invokeCastIron documentation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When you generate an adapter for castiron using the wizard it uses the method WL.Server.invokeCastiron.

I have not been able to find the documentation for this method in the WL 6.0 infocenter.

In the generated code there is a minimum documentation explaining the method inputs and which field is mandatory and not, but there is no documentation about what is each field of the JSON.

Almost all are common with the http adapter but there is one "appName" that I do not know.

Any hit about this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already seen this, the [Castiron Getting Started](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_04_Cast_Iron_adapter_-_Communicating_with_Cast_Iron.pdf) module walks through the setup.

Also see this stackoverflow entry for [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671387/ibm-worklight-invokecastiron-cant-connect-to-cast-iron-live-instance) with Castiron and Worklight.

Comment: Thank you, in the post you mention is clear: "appName and requestType seem to be ignored. I've tried it with them and without them.".
Any way the method should be documented in infocenter that is the official reference documentation.

Comment: True, we've opened a doc defect for this.